# Integrating $ \int \frac{\log^s(x)}{x^{s^2}} \mathrm{d}x $

Tags: calculus, integration

How would I show the following,

> $$ \int \frac{\log^s x}{x^{s^2}} \mathrm{d}x = \log^{s+1}(x) \left((s^2 -1) \log x \right)^{-s-1} \left( -\Gamma(s+1, (s^2 - 1)\log x) \right) + c $$

My attempt: Let $I = \int \frac{\log^s x}{x^{s^2}} \mathrm{d}x$ and $u = x^{-s^2}$ and $\mathrm{d}v = \log^s x \,\mathrm{d}x$. Then we have

$$ I = x^{-s^2} s! x \left(\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^{n-k} \log^k x}{k!} \right) - s! \int x \left(\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^{n-k} \log^k x}{k!} \right) (-s^2) x^{-s^2-1} \mathrm{d}x$$

There's a couple further simplifications, but in general I'm not sure how to continue down this path. I think you can swap the integral and sum, but after that I don't know how to simplify it. I know $\Gamma(a,x) = \int_x^\infty t^{a-1} e^{-t} \mathrm{d}t$ so I figure that plays into the integral expression in the second half.

Comment: ...ewww. Can we at least make this a definite integral to get rid of that $c$? Also, why is the Incomplete Gamma in parentheses? Also, I recommend noting that $s^2-1 = (s+1)(s-1)$ and $-s-1 = -(s+1)$ which means you should probably let $n = s+1$ to simplify the work a bit

Comment: $$\int \frac{\log^{n-1} x}{x^{(n-1)^2}} \mathrm{d}x = -\log^n(x) \left(n(n-2) \log x \right)^{-n}\, \Gamma(n, n(n-2)\log x) + c$$ BTW, what is the motivation for this problem? At the moment it looks like you just threw something into Wolfram Alpha, got a result, and have no idea what to do with it

Comment: The problem is trivial if you write the answer as $$-\log^{s + 1}(x) \operatorname{E}_{-s}[(s^2 - 1) \log(x)] + c$$ Assuming all you want is a proof that the statement is correct, just differentiate this. Easy enough to do with the product rule. You could also obviously start with the integral and get to the answer through a single Integration By Parts (product rule in reverse).

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I was working with a pair of parametric equations when this integral came out, so I put it into wolfram and was curious about the result. There is reason for the integral, but showing the equality is purely out of curiosity.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen How should I split up for IBP? I already tried, but got stuck.

Comment: Why bother with IBP when you can just differentiate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting $x=e^t$ the LHS clearly turns into an incomplete $\Gamma$ function:

$$ \int t^s e^{-(s^2-1)t}\,dt = \frac{1}{(s^2-1)^{s+1}} \int u^s e^{-u}\,du=-\frac{\Gamma(s+1,u)}{(s^2-1)^{s+1}}.$$